# Making two classes into one

Tags: java, class, linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to figure out if there is a way combine my two classes into one. My program is just a circular linked list and I have to use the smallest amount of classes possible. I also would like some help with setting up a method that will let me replace a node with another one. Here are my two classes any thoughts?

The First One:

```
public class Node {

    static int numOfLists = 0;

    int data;
    Node nextNode;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        numOfLists++;

    }
}
```

The Second One:

```
public class LinkedList {

    // i = head
    // j = tail
    static Node i;
    static Node temp;
    static Node j;
    int num;
    Node nextNode;

    public void addNodes(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (j == null) {
            j = node;
            j.nextNode = j;
        } else {
            i = j;

            while (i.nextNode != j) {
                i = i.nextNode;
            }
            i.nextNode = node;
            node.nextNode = j;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        i = j;
        boolean list = false;

        do {
            System.out.print((list) ? "--> |" + i.data + "|" : "|" + i.data
                + "|");
            list = true;
            i = i.nextNode;
        } while (i != j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.addNodes(3);
        list.addNodes(7);
        list.addNodes(2);
        list.addNodes(1);
        list.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the static keywords from the LinkedList implementation. Because of those you will have interference and undefined behavior if you construct and use two or more instances of your LinkedList class. Unless you are trying to construct a class that will manage only one instance of a LinkedList. But then you don't need instance methods, all of those can be static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Using two classes is the right way to go.
Each class has different, well defined responsibilities,
these should be separate classes.
Don't blend them together.
You certainly could, but that would be very bad OOP,
so don't do it.

However, `Node` is an implementation detail of the linked list, that really doesn't need to be visible to users of the linked list. So move Node inside the linked list class as a static inner class, and make it private. That way it will be not visible from the outside, following good principles of encapsulation and information hiding.

Like this (I also cleaned up the rest of the code):

```
public class CircularLinkedList {

    private static class Node {
        private final int data;
        private Node nextNode;

        private Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private Node head;

    public void addNodes(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            head.nextNode = head;
        } else {
            Node runner = head;

            while (runner.nextNode != head) {
                runner = runner.nextNode;
            }
            runner.nextNode = node;
            node.nextNode = head;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Node runner = head;
        boolean first = false;

        do {
            System.out.print((first) ? "--> |" + runner.data + "|" : "|" + runner.data + "|");
            first = true;
            runner = runner.nextNode;
        } while (runner != head);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nested Class like:

```
public class LinkedList {


    static public class Node {
        static int numOfLists = 0;

        int data;
        Node nextNode;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            numOfLists++;

        }
    }
}
```

It is preferable to use static nested class. The number of regular classes is reduced by one but we have one nested class now.

Comment: That would be my idea as well, however it stands to argue, that a nested class is also a separate class, as once you compiled your .java file you end up with two .class files.

Comment: Well yes. But IMO there is no other way to reduce the number of classes.

Comment: THANKS I will try that and does anyone have any tips on how I could replace a Node. I kind of get the general idea but my coding isnt coming out right.

Comment: You would have to have some way to identify a node, so you can iterate through the list, check for equality (using `equals()`) and on a match remove it. Or you could remove it by index, by iterating through your list and keeping track on which element you are currently and once you reach it, remove that one. You need to take care of linking the previous and the next node together in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option if you want to skip traversing the whole list when adding new elements. You still have two references, one for the head and one for the tail. If traversing the list is not a problem then use the solution from @janos.

```
  public class LinkedList
  {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public void addNodes(int data) {
      Node node = new Node(data);
      if (head == null) {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
      } else {
        tail.nextNode = node;
        tail = node;
      }
    }
    public void print() {

      boolean first = true;

      Node currentNode = head;
      while (currentNode != null) {
        System.out.print(!first ? "--> |" + currentNode.data + "|" : "|" + currentNode.data + "|");
        first = false;
        currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
      }
    }


    private static class Node
    {
      int numOfLists = 0;

      int data;
      Node nextNode;

      Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        numOfLists++;

      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you give me some help with making a method that finds a space in the list and replaces that  node with a different one? Do you know any other types of methods I could try and code other than replacing?

Comment: Generally, you should traverse the list and check if the nextNode is not null and nextNode.data is empty. Then replace the nextNode with the replacementNode by changing the two nextNode references. Try writing it and we can then help improve it.